# How to store more than 2 members information?

Tags: drag-and-drop

I have created a registration form using drag and drop and storing details in an array . But the problem is it is storing only one member details . if i fill another details the first member details are replaced by second ones . how i can get solution to this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Create an **array of objects** and use a **looping statement** to **traverse** through the array and with the help of **this** keyword store your information in different objects. This way your **member details** will not be lost.

Comment: can i have some clear information . as i'm new to coding